# c++ define empty multidimensional array and pushback array the array

Tags: c++, arrays

First, how do I define an empty multidimensional array?
Second, how do I then pushback an array into the array?
Where an end result could be something like this: `{ {string1, int1}, {string2, int2}, {string3, int3}, {string4, int4} }`

Comment: arrays cannot change their size. Are you looking for `std::vector` ?

Comment: That might be @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: But how would I go on to do the same as explained but just with vectors instead?

Comment: please include your code in the question. When someone says "array" then from the top of my head I know at least 3 different things that it can refer to and they are all completely different

Comment: Hard for me to include any code when I am trying to build it from the above questions. @largest_prime_is_463035818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the small example you've provided, you want to store a vector of pairs. You can't represent such data in a multidimensional array, because the "inner" array members would need to have different types (`string` and `int`), which is not possible. C++ does not support collections with different types, unlike Python for example where you can just shove all kinds of things into a collection.

The vector of pairs would look like this:

```cpp
struct MyPair{
    std::string myString;
    int myInt;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<MyPair> myVec;
    myVec.push_back(MyPair{"some string", 12});
}
```

Comment: Since we are talking C++, this would be even better `myVec.emplace_back("some string", 12);`

Comment: @TanveerBadar I agree, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. Also wanted to avoid using std::pair to stay more simple and also more general.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Array or vector can contain 1 type of data. If you want to store `{string, int}` pair you can use. `std::pair` and can push it to the vector.

```
std::vector<std::pair<string, int>> data;
auto element = std::make_pair("Name", 20);
data.push_back(element);
```